# how to refresh page and keep pnotify

Tags: jquery, redirect, reload, pnotify

I made a POST form and I send data via ajax and I use PNotify for alert the problem is how i refresh the page and keep the notify box. Or how I redirect the user after submit button to another page and notify box to remain?
I try to put `location.reload()` in success: function but not work... the notify is not displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = $('#editticket');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
  $.ajax({
    type: frm.attr('method'),
    url: frm.attr('action'),
    data: frm.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      new PNotify({
        text: 'Task edited.',
        type: 'info',
        hide: false
      });
    }
  });  
  ev.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some code that will create a new PNotify instance when page is loaded. Simple approach is to pass params using `location.hash`. http://jsfiddle.net/SEVUL/7/

```
function notify() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    if(~hash.indexOf('!PNotify')) {
        new PNotify({text: hash.replace('#!PNotify:', '')});
        location.hash = "";
    }
};

function reload(text) {
    var location = window.location;

    location.hash = "!PNotify:" + text;
    location.reload();
}

$(notify);

$(function() {
    $('#reload').click(function() {
        reload('Some useful info');
    });    
})
```